# python - decode an array of data into predefine value

Tags: python, arrays, case, decode, predefined-variables

I am new to python. I would like to ask how to decode an array of data in python, for example

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5  6  7 8 9 10 4 3 2 4 11 12 13 14 3 2 1 3]
```

and I wanted the output to be like:

```
if data = 1, data become predefined value A
if data = 2, data become predefined value B
... 
if data = 16, data become predefined value X
```

Which function to use in python ? something like case in verilog
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What you have describe can be done by Python's `dictionary` type.

```py
# decoder
numbers_to_words = {1: 'hey', 2: 'this', 3: 'python', 4: 'dictionary', 5: 'is', 6: 'so', 7: 'cool!'}
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for index, data in enumerate(L):
    # here, the current data is replaced by its corresponding decoder value.
    L[index] = numbers_to_words[data]

print(L)
['hey', 'this', 'python', 'dictionary', 'is', 'so', 'cool!']
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting TypeError: unhashable type:'numpy.ndarray',

Comment: Is this method applicable for 2d array?

Comment: I got it using numpy.vectorize

Comment: L = numpy.vectorize(numbers_to_words.get)(L)

Comment: I may be misunderstood your comment. _Is this method applicable for 2d array?_ If you are suggesting to change `L` with a `numpy array`, then you might have to initialize `L = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='object')` for this example. Please refer [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)